# When do I need a datacontract in WCF and would it be better to use a simple type?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization

I am having some trouble designing my WCF service.  Bassically I need the service to recieve an XML document.  The xml maps to a class that was generated from xsd.exe.  I was originally just had this:

```
public void AddDocument(string xmlString)
```

Then I would deserialize the xml into the generated class.  I was told this is a bad idea because I am doing extra work since wcf will do the serialization for me if I just use the document class as a parameter like this:

```
public void AddDocument(MyGeneratedClass document)
```

I'm new to WCF but if I do it this way I thought I would have to create a datacontract for `MyGeneratedClass`.  The generated class is 20,000+ lines so this would take forever.

Do I need a DataContract?  Anyway I think I am missing something so I hope this makes sense and if anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use simple types if your method only requires one or two parameters, and will return only a single simple type value.

As a general rule:

- If you need to pass in more than just a few (less than 5) simple types - use some kind of a `Request` object, otherwise your call gets unwieldy.
- If you need to return more than one single simple type value, use a `Response` object to bundle up those values.

I would try to avoid sending and receiving XML and parse it - try to send back and forth real well structured (data) objects - much easier to deal with and type-safe and all !